# How to find in Salesforce that the Oppotunity is in submit for approval process?

Tags: opportunity, approval-process

I need to know what is the criteria and how to find that particular Opportunity object is in approval process? I presume that some of Opportunity fields is changed. Which is that field and how can I find the value of the field before and after the submit for approval button is pressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do the bare minimum in setting up an Approval Process, the only thing that submitting a record to that Approval Process will do is lock your record.

In other words, there are no fields on your `Opportunity` that will be changed, by default, when that `Opportunity` is submitted for approval.

If you want to check to see if an `Opportunity` is currently in an approval process, there are a few methods you can use:

#### Simple, with Clicks, not code:

The simplest way out of this issue is to create an initial submission action to perform a field update on the record that's being submitted.

You'll be able to choose almost any field that you want, though a standard or custom `Status` field seems to be the most popular choice.

The only other thing that you might have to worry about is to make sure that you also set up a recall, final approval, and final rejection actions to update your chosen field so you know when your record is no longer in the approval process.

#### Least reliable:

You can simply call `System.Approval.isLocked(<opportunityId here>)`.

Approval processes will lock records, so if your `Opportunity` is in approval, the result of this call will be `true`.

However, since Winter '16, [we have had the ability to lock and unlock records via Apex](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_apex_approval_locks_unlocks.htm#rn_apex_approval_locks_unlocks). This means that this check is not infallible.

#### More reliable:

You can query the `ProcessInstance` object to see if any process instance contains your `Opportunity` in its `targetObjectId` field.

To make use of the result, it's probably best to use a SOQL for loop to iterate over the query results and build a set that contains the resulting `targetObjectId`.

A brief example

```
Set<Id> oppIds = trigger.newMap.keySet();
Set<Id> oppIdsInApproval = new Set<Id>();

for(ProcessInstance instance :[SELECT Id, targetObjectId FROM ProcessInstance WHERE targetObjectId IN :oppIds AND completedDate = null]){
    oppIdsInApproval.add(instance.targetObjectId);
}

for(Opportunity opp :trigger.new){
    if(oppIdsInApproval.contains(opp.Id)){
        // In this block, we know that the current Opportunity is in an Approval Process
    } else {
        // In this 'else' block, we know that the current Opportunity is /not/
        //   in an Approval Process
    }
}
```

Now, that query that I used in my example doesn't limit itself to any single approval process. If your record is in *any* approval process, it'll be captured by that query.

If you want to limit things to a specific approval process, just use the following query instead

```
[SELECT Id, targetObjectId FROM ProcessInstance WHERE targetObjectId IN :oppIds AND ProcessDefinitionId IN (SELECT Id FROM ProcessDefinition WHERE DeveloperName = '<process_name_here>')]
```